# Selected tab in jQuery UI broken with v1.9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I upgraded from jQuery 1.7 / UI 1.8.11 to jQuery 1.8.2 / UI 1.9.1 and my code to get the index of the selected tab is no longer working:

```
$('#tabContainer').tabs('option', 'selected')
```

This used to return `0` if the first tab was selected, but now it's just returning the `tabContainer` element (a div).  I read in the UI 1.9 release notes that `selected` was deprecated, but `active` (the replacement) gives the same result.

Is there a different way to get the selected tab index from outside the tabs() function?

Thanks!

Comment: According to the documentation it should be returning an integer. Are you sure you aren't getting an integer with "active"? In either case, if you have the tab container, you should be able to get it's index with `.index()`

Comment: When I evaluate the code above with `active` in Chrome Dev Tools, it's returning an object.  `$('#tabContainer > ul > li.ui-tabs-active').index()` gets what I want, but it's a workaround.